# Is it possible to select multiple objects inside Intellisense box?

Tags: ssms

Is it possible to select multiple options inside this box?

[image]

Comment: Its name is "Intellisense". Pretty sure you *can't* change it's colour, and selecting multiple items doesn't make sense; Intellisense will have no idea what the `JOIN` requirements are for the query you're writing.

Comment: Its Statement completing item. But how select multiple object inside of it?

Comment: Again, it makes no sense to select multiple objects in it.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, nor does it make sense to. When writing a query you need to be specific on what you want, and how you want that data to relate

Take the image in your question, where you are selecting a table name, if you select 2 tables, how is that meant to appear in the query? To have 2 tables in the query you need a `JOIN`. What type of `JOIN` should that be? An `INNER JOIN`? a `LEFT` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`? Perhaps a `FULL OUTER JOIN` or even a `CROSS JOIN`? If any but the last, what is the `ON` clause for said `JOIN`?

What about if it were a function? Would the other functions be called with a `CROSS APPLY` or an `OUTER APPLY`? What are the values of the parameters?

Intellisense doesn't know what *you* want, only you know that. It's prompting potential options to you, in this case objects that match the name of what you've typed already, but it doesn't know what you're going to do with those objects afterwards. It's not able to predict your intentions; it's just listing objects names that match your existing text.

Intellisense is there to *assist* you write the queries but it's not there to *literally* write them for you; that's for you to do.

Comment: If I want to add some columns in the SELECT clause then it makes sense to select multiple columns objects.

Comment: Intellisense is just a prompting tool, @MisterXAGE_ , that's all. Don't expect it to write your code for you; it won't.